# Apache POI: Why Is a Row Missing When I use shiftRows?

Tags: scala, apache-poi

I'm shifting the rows in an excel sheet and inserting a new row at the beginning of the sheet.  However, regardless of how many rows I shift and insert, I seem to be ending up with one less row than I should be.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
import   Row.MissingCellPolicy._
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.WorkbookUtil.createSafeSheetName
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

def shiftAndInsertRow(sheet: Sheet) = {

  val rowInsertionPoint = 0

  // shift all the rows down
  val lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum
  println(s"Last row is $lastRowNum")

  val debugRow1 = sheet.getRow(rowInsertionPoint)
  val debugCell1 = debugRow1.getCell(0)
  // let's get a play-by-play of what's being attempted
  println(s"Current value in row $rowInsertionPoint is " +
      s"${debugCell1.getNumericCellValue}")
  println(s"Shifting rows $rowInsertionPoint and below down one row")
  sheet.shiftRows(rowInsertionPoint, lastRowNum, 1, true, true)
  val debugRow2 = sheet.getRow(rowInsertionPoint + 1)
  val debugCell2 = debugRow2.getCell(0)
  println(s"Current value in row ${rowInsertionPoint + 1} is now " +
      s"${debugCell2.getNumericCellValue}")

  println(s"Creating new row at $rowInsertionPoint in sheet")
  // create the new row
  val newRow = sheet.createRow(rowInsertionPoint)
  // set the field ID of the row
  val newCell = newRow.getCell(0, CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)
  println(s"Inserting value $lastRowNum at $rowInsertionPoint in sheet")
  newCell.setCellValue(lastRowNum)
  println()

}

val workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()
val sheet = workbook.createSheet(createSafeSheetName("Test 1"))
val rowNum = 0
val cellValue = -1

println(s"Creating new row at $rowNum in sheet")
// create the new row
val row = sheet.createRow(rowNum)
// set the field ID of the row
val cell = row.getCell(0, CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)
println(s"Inserting value $cellValue at $rowNum in sheet")
cell.setCellValue(cellValue)
println()
// insert a second row
shiftAndInsertRow(sheet)
// and a third
shiftAndInsertRow(sheet)
workbook.write(new java.io.FileOutputStream("out/test.xlsx"))
```

The above code creates a spreadsheet with only two rows instead of three.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is fine, it looks to me like this is a bug in apache-poi. It works for me on version 3.17 but breaks if  I upgrade to 4.0.0.

As far as I can tell, the row num is being updated correctly, but the reference (`cell.getReference`) is not.

I would suggest trying to find if the bug has already been reported here https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI and if not, filing a new bug report.

In the meantime, you could perhaps try this workaround which seems to do the trick for me. It calls `updateCellReferencesForShifting` on every cell in the spreadsheet.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
for {
  row <- sheet.rowIterator().asScala.toList
  cell <- row.cellIterator().asScala.toList
} yield cell.asInstanceOf[XSSFCell].updateCellReferencesForShifting("")
```

Place this block of code right after your call to `shiftRows`. No guarantees that it's not going to break something else though, so use with caution!

Comment: Seems like 4.x is unstable.  I've found another issue.